# how to UPDATE using mysql_insert_id() into different table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql_insert_id() on the first page (test2.php) to insert the same id on other tables that is submitted from different forms. The id is inserted perfectly however, when i want to insert the data from other forms (e.g: test.php), the data cannot be updated, I have to inform before this i was using insert and it is not systematic because it will insert a new data with new id. As reference, below are my php codings for page test2.php and test.php:

**test2.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("auth.php");
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('tempahperalatan');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $noID = $_POST['noID'];
    $pemohon = $_POST['pemohon'];
    $trkhMula = $_POST['trkhMula'];
    $trkhAkhir = $_POST['trkhAkhir'];
    $n_program = $_POST['n_program'];
    $lokasi = $_POST['lokasi'];
    $n_anjuran = $_POST['n_anjuran'];
    $catatan = $_POST['catatan'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO daftartempah (noID, pemohon, trkhMula, trkhAkhir, n_program, lokasi, n_anjuran, catatan) values ('$noID','$pemohon','$trkhMula','$trkhAkhir','$n_program','$lokasi','$n_anjuran','$catatan')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pasystems (noID) values ('$noID')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ict_1 (noID) values ('$noID')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pejabat (noID) values ('$noID')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
}

?>
```

For page test.php, there is an echo of variables is because I was testing whether it reads the variables, and surprisingly it reads because it appear at the top of the page of the data that I entered however, the noID does not appear and that means it does not fetch the same id from the previous page (test2.php) and I think that is the problem why my data was not updated. Can anyone help me about this problem because I'm a student studying web programming and some guidance would be so helpful, thank you in advance.

**test.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("auth.php");
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('tempahperalatan');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $noID = $_POST['noID'];
    $microphones = $_POST['microphones'];
    $amplifiers = $_POST['amplifiers'];
    $loudspeakers = $_POST['loudspeakers'];
    $mixers = $_POST['mixers'];
    $catatan = $_POST['catatan'];

    ?>
    <p><?php    echo $microphones;echo $amplifiers; echo $loudspeakers; echo $mixers; echo $catatan; echo $noID; ?></p>
    <?php

mysql_query ("UPDATE pasystems SET microphones='$microphones', amplifiers='$amplifiers', loudspeakers='$loudspeakers', catatan='$catatan' WHERE noID = '$noID'");


}
```

Please ask if my question is not clear for you to help me, I will try to help you understand my problem/question.

Comment: stop using the depreciated mysql_*

Comment: @nogad its the only coding of mysql_insert_id() i found on the internet, as I said, I'm just a student I've been searching for the codings in months.

Comment: you have used myqli in previous questions why not here

Comment: @nogad because for mysql_insert_id() function that i found are only in mysql, i tried changing it into mysqli but it is not compatible.

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id($con)` i really dont see the problem